# How i can get image from printer "Scanner"

Tags: java, image, file, image-scanner

I want to get image from printer "Scanner" by using java code , and after get image i want to save it on project folder , How i can do that ?

```
 public static void main(String args[]) {
    }
```

Comment: Windows , NetBeans :)

Comment: Are you aware that `Scanner` will help you to get the user input and not an image, right? Also, NetBeans is just a tool that helps you create Java applications.

Comment: yes , i know netbeans it`s a tool , and i mean by "scanner" the device that use to scan the image , NOT scanner class :)

Comment: You're going to need a native interface to talk to the scanner via what ever driver implementation the scanner supports.  Under Windows, the two primary protocols are TWAIN and WIA.  Personally, I'd recommend [Morena](http://www.gnome.sk/Morena/morena.html), mostly because it has a nice "personal" use license which I've used a lot

Comment: I strongly disagree, that this question should be closed. It is rather seldom topic, and most of java programmers know nothing of it, and don't know where to get any info. So do I.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can take a look at this [framework](http://www.gnome.sk/Twain/jtp.html).

Comment: is it FREE? why not FREE? why all of them are asking money?

Answer (score 2):

try this,

```
 try {

        Source source = SourceManager.instance().getDefaultSource(); 
        // Acquire image from default source
        source.open();

        Image image = source.acquireImage(); // Acquire the image

        // Loads the image completely ...
        // Click here to find how to load images completely with MediaTracker.
        // ...

        int imageWidth = image.getWidth(this);
        int imageHeight = image.getHeight(this);

        BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(imageWidth, imageHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

        Graphics2D g2 = bufferedImage.createGraphics();
        g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);

        // Now, you can use the bufferedImage object ...

    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        SourceManager.closeSourceManager();
    }
```

Reference : http://asprise.com/product/jtwain/faq.php