# How Can I write a java code which scan a image from physical scanner device?

Tags: java, scanning, image-scanner

I need to connect physical scanner device and send scanning request then get the image.
I got it by using asprise-imaging-core.jar but unfortunately its not free

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Morena](https://www.gnome.sk/Twain/jtp.html) seems to be a free Java TWAIN library for non-commercial use (I haven't used it).

Also see

- [How i can get image from printer "Scanner"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17266829/how-i-can-get-image-from-printer-scanner)
- [TWAIN/WIA example for java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27959457/twain-wia-example-for-java)
- And here's someone who managed to wrap a free DLL with JNI (apparently after fixing some bugs in the DLL): https://www.infoworld.com/article/2074455/bridge-the-gap-between-java-and-twain.html

Comment: I have used Morena, and it is working quite fine.